# Where can I find a pet Cuddlefish?

Tags: subnautica

Now that Subnautica has officially left Early Access (yay!), I've started playing it again. I've heard rumors about a new creature that is tameable as a pet called the Cuddlefish, but I don't know where to find it.

I've searched a few of the nearest biomes (Safe Shallows, Kelp Forest, Grassy Plateaus, and Crags), but I've had no luck so far. I don't want to look it up in the wiki just yet because I'm trying to avoid spoilers. Where can I find one? Do I need anything special to tame it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to hatch the [Cuddlefish](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Cuddlefish)  from an egg.  The [eggs](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Eggs#Normal_Eggs) can be found in

> - [Deep Grand Reef Degasi Base](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Degasi_Seabases)
> - [Dunes Sinkhole](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Dunes)
> - [Lost River Laboratory](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_Caches)
> - [Northeastern Mushroom Forest Caves](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Mushroom_Forest_Caves)
> - [Northwestern Mushroom Forest Caves](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Mushroom_Forest_Caves)

So far, I've only seen people find them in the first location above, as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bu78WPQXA4).  After you obtain the egg, place it in an [Alien Containment](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Containment) tank and wait for it to hatch (apparently its about 1 to 3 in game days).

Comment: Northwestern Mushroom Forest, bottom-most cavern under the huge mushroom is probably the easiest to reach, safest location.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently five Cuddlefish eggs hidden throughout the game. You may find additional Cuddlefish in time capsules if you're lucky enough to have such capsules spawn in your game.

I created a walkthrough which shows you where to find all five Cuddlefish eggs. While filming, I did find six due to stumbling upon a time capsule.

Here are coordinates for the eggs:

1. **Northeastern Mushroom Forest** at 712, -266, 531
2. **Northwestern Mushroom Forest** at -866, -150, 600
3. **The Dunes** at -1502, -408, 501
4. **Deep Grand Reef Degasi Base** at -639, -487, -953
5. **The Lost River** at -1115, -685, -660

Once you find the eggs, you will need to hatch them in an alien containment tank in your base.